# Comparar campos em jQuery

Tags: jquery

Preciso comparar os campos conforme o script abaixo:

```
    $("#send_request").submit(function(event){
        var password  = '7c4a8d09ca3762af61e59520943dc26494f8941b'; 
        if($('#userpassword').val()!=password){
            alert('senha invalida');
        }
      event.preventDefault();
    });
```

Só que a senha do `userpassword` deste campo, virá sem criptografia, então, vou ter que criptografar antes de comparar. Mas o form passa direto, nem compara e não dá em nada. Como devo fazer?

Comment: Não envies passwords para o lado do cliente! Mesmo que faças `var pwd = <?= pd ?>;` isso vai ser acessível pelo utilizador. Para além disso uma password encriptada em hash nunca é igual a uma password inserida num campo `input type="password"`.

Tens de usar ajax, enviar isso para o PHP e lá fazer a comparação.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sem ver o código html do form fica meio complicado, mas o seu código js me parece estar ok, consegui fazer ele rodar aqui sem mais problemas, sem levar em consideração que não está criptografando nada ainda. O meu form fiz assim, olhe se está de acordo:

```html
<form id="send_request" action="#" method="POST">
  <input id="userpassword" type="text">
  <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

```js
$("#send_request").submit(function(event){  
  var password  = '7c4a8d09ca3762af61e59520943dc26494f8941b'; 
  if($('#userpassword').val()!=password){
    alert('senha invalida');
  }
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Teoricamente é isso, mas na hora de clicar no botão, ele não dá em nada, e vai para o action do form... e precisava criptografar o userpassword, em php.,.. eu criptografo ele assim oh <?=$this->encrypt->sha1($accounts_details->security_password);?> como eu coloco ele ali no jquery?

Comment: Bom, você pode chamar uma página sua em php via AJAX pra pegar o SHA1 da senha, ou então usar alguma biblioteca javascript pra fazer em tempo de execução.

Comment: Outra abordagem é deixar o form submeter, e na sua página php fazer o tratamento e verificação, caso a senha digitada não seja igual, volta para a página do form e mostra alguma mensagem para o usuário.

Comment: Sim, eu já fiz dessa forma... mas será que dá pra fazer voltar e com o form preenchido? to pensando em registrar eles no cookies

Comment: Dá sim. (: até em sessão dá pra por esses dados também.

Comment: Lembrando que o ideal, como o Sérgio comentou lá em cima, é não enviar passwords pelo lado cliente, é perigoso. Eu apenas tentei responder sua pergunta de acordo com a sua dúvida, mas temos que ter cuidado ao tratar os dados dos usuários. Abraço!

Comment: Sim, eu tratei a questão pelo PHP, e fiz o retorno caso o password digitado não seja o dele, ou incorreto, porém, no retorno os campos vem vazios em caso de erro, mas vou salvar o POST na session ou nos cookies, e preencho os campos em caso de erro